# Зачеркнуть текст у Телеграм бота

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бота на php. Встал вопрос о перечеркивании слов выводимых ботом.

Я видел подобных ботов. И даже видел мануал о том как написать такого бота. Однако там бот был написан на Node JS. Попытки задействовать спец символы не увенчались успехом. Помогите с данным вопросом.

Вот мануал по написанию бота http://telegra.ph/Razbor-bota-kotoryj-zacherkivaet-tekst-07-31

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашел решение. Нужно использовать спец символ `&#822;` перед каждой буквой. Но с  увы не работает.